# How to set Time object from EditText Android?

Tags: android, date, time, countdown

I am trying to set a countdown in my android app based on a date that the user inputs.

So the user has a date picker that sets a date in a an EditText object and then when I click save I need it to take the value from the EditText object and run the code below:

```
final EditText dateField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dateSentData);  
        String dateSent = dateField.getText().toString();
        Double date = Double.parseDouble(dateSent);

        Time TimerSet = new Time();
        TimerSet.set(date); //day month year
        TimerSet.normalize(true);
        long millis = TimerSet.toMillis(true);

        Time TimeNow = new Time();
        TimeNow.setToNow(); // set the date to Current Time
        TimeNow.normalize(true);
        long millis2 = TimeNow.toMillis(true);

        long millisset = millis - millis2; //subtract current from future to set the time remaining

        final int smillis = (int) (millis); //convert long to integer to display conversion results
        final int smillis2 = (int) (millis2);

new CountDownTimer(millisset, 1000) {
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                mText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.weddingDateData);

                // decompose difference into days, hours, minutes and seconds 
                int weeks = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) /
                        604800);
                int days = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 86400);
                int hours = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000) - (days
                        * 86400)) / 3600);
                int minutes = (int) (((millisUntilFinished / 1000) - ((days
                        * 86400) + (hours * 3600))) / 60);
                int seconds = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60);
                int millicn = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                mText.setText(" " +days);
            }
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        }.start();
```

The code above wont run as it say that on the following line it doesn't except a String or Double only a Long:

```
TimerSet.set(date);
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can set the date and time changing this

```
TimerSet.set(date);
```

with this

```
//TimerSet.set(int second, int minute, int hour, int monthDay, int month, int year) This is the structure for method TimerSet
TimerSet.set(0,25,24,12,7,2013);
```

So the date and time should be 12/07/2013 24:25:00

But i think theres an issue with the date, when i send a toast with TimerSet

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "date: "+ TimerSet, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

It says that the date i set is this 13/08/2013 24:25:00

So what i did is to change this

```
Time TimerSet = new Time();
TimerSet.set(0,25,24,12,7,2013);
```

With this (Note that i decrease the month and day by 1)

```
int year = 2013;
int month = 7 - 1;
int day = 12 - 1;
int hour = 24;
int minutes = 55;
int seconds = 0;

Time TimerSet = new Time();
//set(int second, int minute, int hour, int monthDay, int month, int year)
TimerSet.set(seconds,minutes,hour,day,month,year);
```

With this it gives me the correct date 12/07/2013 24:25:00

Hope this help you or if you have other solution please tell me how to solve by other way.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

The method `Time.set` expects a long value which represents milliseconds since the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

You'll have to parse the date in another way, depending on the date format you receive as input.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example of how to do this please?

Comment: Use `SimpleDateFormat`. For example, if your format is day/month/year: `Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dateSent);`